# Write a cursor to search and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I have tables like that:

Main

```
id name   isedit 
1   kyle   0
2   jhon   1
3   dave   0
```

EditHistory

```
id idmain name isedit  Begin                end
1  2      jhon  0      28.05.2020 18:30    28.05.2020 18:35
2  2      jhon  0      28.05.2020 18:35     NULL
3  1      kyle  0      27.05.2020 12:03      NULL
```

I currently use trigger:

```
(…)       if update(isedit) and exists (
        select 1
        from Inserted I
        where design = 0

      ) begin
        Insert into dbo.HistoryEdit
            ([idmain][name][isedit][Begin][end]) SELECT id, name, iedit, GETDATE(), null
        from Inserted 
      end;
```

I need to create cursor that will check through `EditHistory` for previous rows with same `idmain` and if there is such row edit its end date to `GETDATE()` and insert into `HistoryEdit` as in my current insert.

I know it can be easily done with IF's and thats how I would do it. But I have to use cursor for that, and I never used cursor before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I never used cursor before.

Well don't start now.  Just update the older rows before you insert the newer ones:

```
declare @d datetime = GetDate()

update EditHistory set end = @d
where id in (select id from inserted)
  and end is null;

Insert into dbo.HistoryEdit
    ([idmain][name][isedit][Begin][end]) 
SELECT id, name, iedit, @d, null
from Inserted
```

Comment: I know that way however it have to be done with cursor

Comment: Thats the task I got

Comment: Well, either tell them that's dumb and you shouldn't use a cursor for that, or go learn how to write cursors.  There's lots of tutorials on the internet.